# Dynamic select options failing in lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, lightbox

I have a lightbox which is being used to house a form. there are two choices, Select UK or US and each has its own list associated it to it.

I have created the logic behind this yet outside of the lightbox it works, but once added in it fails and does not switch to the relevant options when you select either country?

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5CKA4/)

Here is the script, I am using lightbox featherlight too.

```
 <select class="country">
    <option value="US">US</option>
    <option value="UK">UK</option>
</select>

<select class="model">
    <option></option>
</select>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    var selectValues = {
        "UK": {
            "County1": "",
            "County2": ""
        },
        "US": {
            "State1": "",
            "State2": ""
        }
    };

    var $vendor = $('select.country');
    var $model = $('select.model');
    $vendor.change(function() {
        $model.empty().append(function() {
            var output = '';
            $.each(selectValues[$vendor.val()], function(key, value) {
                output += '<option>' + key + '</option>';
            });
            return output;
        });
    }).change();

});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Lightbox creates a copy of the div. You have to connect up the events of the select boxes when you first load the dialog. Luckily you can get a reference to the dialog you have just opened.

```
$("#openDialogButton").click(function () {
    var dlg = $.featherlight("#fl1",
        {
            otherClose: ".btn", //any .btn will close the dialog
            closeOnEsc: true
        }
    ); //open the featherlight dialog
    //FIND THE SELECT BOXES within the dialog you have just opened
    var $vendor = dlg.$content.find('select.country');
    var $model = dlg.$content.find('select.model');
    $vendor.change(function () { 
        $model.empty().append(function () {
            var output = '';
             $.each(selectValues[$vendor.val()], function (key, value) {
                 output += '<option>' + key + '</option>';
             });
             return output;
         });
     }).change();
});
```

When you come to save the results of the dialog you can't use $("select.model"). You have to navigate from the this object e.g.

```
$("#dialogOKButton").click(function () {
    var theCommentText = $("#commentText").val(); // null!
    theCommentText = $(
            $(this).parent()
        ).find("#commentText")
        .val(); // have to navigate from this
    alert("you entered this text " 
        + theCommentText + " and clicked OK");
});
```